# linux/types.h:21:1: error: unknown type name '__u16'

Tags: c, android-ndk

I have used ndk revision r10d on my machine to compile and run sample programs successfully before. But this new project, which uses the same header file stdio.h gives the following error(s). The errors are from a file, which stdio references. And although I do not see the variables defined in the file, I want to understand how it worked last time. The errors are from /linux/types.h file stating that __16 is not defined type.

@Michael - Thanks. I did what you suggested, and here is the Android.mk file and results of compile. Basically the API level is changed, but the error persists:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
# give module name
APP_PLATFORM := android-18
LOCAL_MODULE := hello_tz  
$(warning This is in NDK_ROOT $(NDK_ROOT))
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/$(APP_PLATFORM)/arch-arm/usr/include
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a15
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -mcpu=cortex-a15 -march=armv7-a
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__ASSEMBLY__ -mabi=aapcs-linux -gdwarf-2 -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-
aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -Wno
-maybe-uninitialized -marm -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -fstack-protector -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -funwind-tables 
-D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 -mcpu=cortex-a15 -msoft-float -Uarm -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-
frame-pointer -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOT
O
# list your C files to compile
FILE_LIST := $(patsubst %.c,%.c.arm,$(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.c))
#$(warning here is what is in FILE_LIST after an attempt to collect all the C files$(FILE_LIST))
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.s)
#$(warning here is what is in FILE_LIST after an attempt to collect all the S files$(FILE_LIST))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
# this option will build executables instead of building library for android application.
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)


In file included from /home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:39:0,
                 from /home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdio.h:50,
                 from jni/main_normal.c:1:
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:1: error: unknown type name '__u16'
 typedef __u16 __bitwise __le16;
 ^
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/types.h:22:1: error: unknown type name '__u16'
 typedef __u16 __bitwise __be16;
 ^
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/types.h:23:1: error: unknown type name '__u32'
 typedef __u32 __bitwise __le32;
 ^
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/types.h:24:1: error: unknown type name '__u32'
 typedef __u32 __bitwise __be32;
 ^
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/types.h:26:1: error: unknown type name '__u64'
 typedef __u64 __bitwise __le64;
 ^
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/types.h:27:1: error: unknown type name '__u64'
 typedef __u64 __bitwise __be64;
 ^
In file included from /home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdio.h:50:0,
                 from jni/main_normal.c:1:
/home/sansari/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:42:1: error: unknown type name '__u32'
 typedef __u32    __kernel_dev_t;
```

Comment: Have you added the NDK include directory to your include path? (e.g. `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include`). Btw, did you really intend to use `android-3` as your platform? That's quite old.

Comment: _"I did not configure android3. How can I change that please"_ With `APP_PLATFORM` in Application.mk (e.g. `APP_PLATFORM := android-18`, or whichever platform you want to use). You can then refer to this as `$(APP_PLATFORM)` in your Android.mk when you specify the include path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As my solution, I expanded the types.h file:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 WITH Linux-syscall-note */
#ifndef _LINUX_TYPES_H
#define _LINUX_TYPES_H

#include <asm/types.h>

#ifndef __ASSEMBLY__

#include <linux/posix_types.h>

/* ## Gerhard Quell, gquell@skequell.com 20240110 */
#ifndef __u16
typedef unsigned short __u16;
#endif

#ifndef __u32
typedef unsigned int __u32;
#endif

#ifndef __s32
typedef int __s32;
#endif

#ifndef __u64
typedef long unsigned long int __u64;
#endif

#ifndef __s64
typedef long long int __s64;
#endif

/* ## Gerhard Quell -------------------------------------- */
```

...